What parameter decides MOSFET switching response?
I've been playing with some LTSpice simulations of some MOSFETs, the circuit is just an op-amp current source which receives a PWM signal to control the current. Below is some transient simulations of the circuit.


On the left is the circuit using an RFD16N06LE MOSFET (datasheet) and on the right using an IRF520N (datasheet).
As you can see the current responses through R1 are noticeably different, with the RFD16N06LE having a significantly lower "damping factor" (if that's the right way of putting it).
What I'm interested to know is what parameter / feature of the two MOSFETs causes these different responses - i.e. is there some way I would be able to predict how a given MOSFET would respond to this circuit just by looking at its datasheet?
EDIT:
After more experimenting I've found another difference between the two.

The graphs above (still RFD16N06LE on the left, IRF520N on the right) show how current through R1 changes with V1, as you can see the current increases linearly up to a point and then levels out, but the point at which it levels out is different for the two MOSFETs, can someone explain this?
Thanks! :)

You should try this same comparison using an ideal op-amp because the GS capacitance difference and limited drive capability of the LT1013 will discolour the waveform comparison. You should also look at the current of R2 and not R1 because R1 also receives gate charge currents from the op-amp. In other words, a more targeted experiment is required.

It's not 'just' an op-amp current source. The circuit is already very complicated. In order to tease apart the effects of different parameters, you will need to simplify it.

try replacing the opamp with a pulse voltage source. (right click on a voltage source and select pulse).  this will give you an ideal source instead of mixing in opamp attributes.

A MOSFET switching speed is mostly determine by how fast you can charge and discharge the gate charge, usually shown as Qg (total gate charge) on the data sheet).
Thus for fast switching you need a gate driver that can deliver a high current  to rapidly move the charge. An op amp can only deliver a small maximum current, so the MOSFET switching time is slow.
That's why, for high-speed switching, a MOSFET gate is often driven by dedicated gate-driver ICs that can deliver the required high current.
